# Why two floated block-level elements can co-exist on the same line while not touching each other?

Tags: css, css-float

I'm looking deeper into CSS floats and I can't really find a reason for this. (title)

According to MDN,

> As mentioned above, when an element is floated,
> it is taken out of the normal flow of the document (though still remaining part of it).
> It is shifted to the left, or right, until it touches the edge of its containing box, or another floated element.

So something like this

```css
.container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.left {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid purple;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

is easily understandable.

But why this happens when changing the right box's float property to right?

```css
.container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.left {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid purple;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this might happen because the first element with float "disappears" from the flow of the page, so it allows other elements to stand on the same line.

Am I right?

Can anybody help me understand this better?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand :D could you add what you expected to happen in contrast to what actually happens?

Comment: @NicoShultz haha :) okay, I'll try to make it shorter and clearer - why can two block elements be on the same line if one is floated left and one is floated right?

Comment: why the first one is intuitive for you but not the second one? for me the second one is the intuitive one

Comment: in the first one float works exactly like in the definition. "It is shifted to the left, or right, until it touches the edge of its containing box, or another floated element." - it touches the other floated element on the left. But when I float it to the right, it stays on the same line as the other one, and I can't understand why.

Comment: *But when I float it to the right* --> it touches the edge of its containing block. Read the sentence again : It is shifted to the left, **or right**, until it touches the edge of its **containing box,** or another floated element.

Comment: That's true. But why does it stay on the same line with another floated left element? that's my question. It should touch the edge of the containing box on another line.

Comment: where it says it should go to another line?

Comment: They are two block level elements - that's why, I think.

Comment: in this case, why the first one seems logical to you? they are still two block level elements and they are kept in the same line

Comment: Because in the first one it touches the edge of another floated element. In the second one it doesn't, but it still stays on the same line.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats : *If there is not enough horizontal room for the float, it is shifted downward until either it fits or there are no more floats present.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That link solved my problem.